# Binary Search Tree "not a procedure" issue for In-Order-Traversal in Racket/Scheme/Lisp

Tags: search, scheme, racket

```lisp
(define (inOrderTraverse root)
  (cond
    [(not (list? root)) (display root)]
    [else (
      (inOrderTraverse (getLeftChild root))
      (display (getValue root))
      (inOrderTraverse (getRightChild root))
    )]
  )
)
```

This gives me:
[image]

I tried replacing `cond` with `if`, but that didn't work.
I looked up online for similar approaches and found:

```lisp
(define (inorder ~node func)
    (unless (empty? ~node)
      (inorder (node-left ~node) func)
      (print (node-val ~node)) (print ", ")
      (inorder (node-right ~node) func)))
```

from a gist of github/arjunvasan. After editing their code to fit mine, it worked perfectly, with the only difference being that they used `unless` instead of `cond`.
Why does `unless` work better here? I checked the racket docs on this keyword but still haven't found it.

Comment: Your code is trying to use whatever `(inOrderTraverse (getLeftChild root))` returns as a function. Gotta pay more attention to your parens. Better code formatting would help.

Comment: The problem is that you wrapped the `else` body in parentheses.  Parentheses are not used for indicating block structure in Scheme.